# Becoming colorless my vs code code Closure is not the end of the road for questions;

Tags: colors, fonts

when I write code my vs code code become colorless

```
type[Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yt4T2.png) here
```

I tried to fix this problem but dies not work. I changed the color theme and font family color but again and again it does not fix. What should I do please help me